# Modify an input float label script to also work for textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a float label script that works for input box. How would I change the script below to make it work for textarea? I added the $fields.on("textarea", floatLabel) to the script but it didn't work. Any help?

```
(function($){
   var $fields = $(".floatLabel");

   // when data is entered...
   $fields.on("input", floatLabel);
   $fields.on("textarea", floatLabel);

   // Check the text fields as soon as the document loads for data that 
   // may have been added upon load
   floatLabel();

   function floatLabel(){
     $fields.each(function(i, f){
       var $field = $(f);
       if($field.val().trim() === "" || $field.val() === "blank"){
         $field.next().removeClass("active");
       } else {
         $field.next().addClass("active");
       }
     });
   }
})(jQuery);
```

CSS

```
.controls label.active {
    position:relative;
    top: -50px;
    left:-175px;
    color: #555;
    background-color: white;
}

.controls label {
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    left:-175px;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: color 0.3s, top 0.3s, background-color 0.8s;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-row">
  <div class="field-wrap">
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" class="floatLabel" name="property_address" value="<?php echo $address?>" required>
      <label for="property_address">Street Address</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two-row">
    <div class="field-wrap">
      <div class="controls">
        <textarea name="comments" class="floatLabel">value="<?php echo $comments?>"</textarea>
        <label for="comments"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `textarea` is not an event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misinterpreted the use of

```
$fields.on("Input")
```

It does not mean "on inputbox" but on the input event, as in receiving input. So changing it to "textarea" does nothing, since that event does not exist. So you should remove that line.

Also, when you call your function you can directly call it like this:

```
$fields.on("input", floatLabel())
```

You won't need the extra floatLabel() in between. Because that will be executed as soon as the script loads.

Edit: I don't know if the textarea even has an 'input' event. But maybe you should take a look at the keyup event?

https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately, I don't have enough knowledge nor experience to do a proper change with the keyup event. I just learned about all of this in about a month.

Comment: $fields.on("keyup", floatLabel()) , this should do it I think. Can I suggest it might be easier to start from a tutorial or online video or lessons? It can take a long time learning it like this and you'll probably end up a spaghetti coder if you don't properly learn from the basics.